# Phonegap/cordova localNotifications plugin working on emulator, but not on device

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, localnotification

I'm using https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

I have strange issue, notification are showing in emulator, but not on real device.

I make a simple call when app is in background:

```
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        title: 'Hello',
        message: 'world'
    });
```

And nothing happens. I tested from Safari console, `registerPermissions` passes `true` in callback, and I have Pushwoosh plugin ( https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1297 ) working well with push notifications.

I tested on iPhone 5 iOS 7.1, iPhone 4S iOS 7.0 and iPad 2 iOS 8.1.2 with PhoneGap Build.

In emulator everything works perfect.

**UPD**

It works if I schedule delayed notification in foreground at 5 secs from now, then bring app to background. Seems that I can't trigger instant notification from background somehow.

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall the app from your IOS, are you sure it is deleting all the cache and data associated with the app?

Ref:
http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Application-Data-in-iOS

and then try to install it on the device again.

I also assume you are creating a debug version via cordova, so you can check the log of what is triggered when you load the app on the phone?

Comment: How can cache and data be related to local notifications be shown or not? I went through those steps from instruction, installed again, but nothing changed. By the way, it wasn't any new confirmation popup about receiving notifications from app. Didn't understand about log. Where can I turn the debug mode on and where to find that log? Thank you.

Comment: Data and cache are related in a sense that if reinstalling the app does not do a clean reinstall, but there are leftovers in the cache or where the data is saved on the device, it might load these "old" settings from that left-over-cache, and thus not show you the all-new-installed app. I mentined it as it is worth checking.

For debugging, did you try to find any info?
https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/debugging/